# how can I send the real-time database to the registered user email that created using Firebase??

Tags: android, firebase

I am trying to get data and send them to the registered users. The data will be stored in the database by a registered user and then a user can get his own database that he/she created from his registered email.

Comment: can you share your data structure? because if you use ref.setValue() method then it does not generate key.

Comment: This sounds like an odd design pattern for Firebase. With Firebase, the user can access whatever data you permit access to via your app - there's no need to 'send data' when they already have access to it. Perhaps you could enhance your question with a use case, add some code as to what you've tried and a snippet of your Firebase structure as well.

Answer (score 0):

In Firebase every use that gets registered has it unique **UUID** key, you can find that key right next to user email. Now simple make a node of users and in that users node make another node with the random generated **UUID** in that node save user data and id of user, and that id will be the one **UUID** which was generated when user was created.

And now simple apply Firebase query.

```
Query query = ref.orderByChild('id').equalTo(userID);//User ID is the UUID created when user signed up
query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot movieSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                        if (movieSnapshot.getLead().equals('Jack Nicholson')) {
                            console.log(movieSnapshot.getKey());
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

                }
            });
```

Hope this helps